# Why doesn't Ubuntu 18.04 keep network config in place after install?

Tags: networking, system-installation

I am installing 18.04 Server with the network mini.iso as a VM and using IPv6 DHCP. I have no IPv4 WAN addresses available.

The installation works fine. I give the installer the DNS servers and it configures the rest over DHCP. All packages are downloaded OK over the WAN during the install (at least, I assume they are!). However, when the installation finishes, I have no network and I have to configure it manually. Note that networking **is** configured after install (as IPv6 DHCP in my case), but with no DNS servers.

Why is this? Should not the installer apply the network configs it used?

Comment: There is only 1 person that can answer this: the maintainer of the package. I suggest you post a bug report on launchpad.

Comment: unless you're installing the server version of Ubuntu 18.04, any settings you configured for the installer will not persist into the installed instance. The installer is a Live Boot instance, which you can read more about at https://www.linux.com/learn/live-booting-linux. Basically the entire OS is run off of your ram/swap, without touching your hard drive, so no changes other than the actual installation are made.

Comment: sure. but but there is also: username, password, date and timezone and a couple of other things kept in memory but save to disk at some point. Oh and regular Ubuntu itself remembers my wifi password if I insert it during installation. So I agree with the question that it should be possible though it is a matter of opinion..

Comment: I'm installing the server version, if that helps. @rizwind The maintainer of the Ubuntu installer package? Also, networking IS configured after install (as IPv6 DHCP in my case), but with no DNS servers. This, coupled with the fact that I'm completely failing to work out how to modify the netplan .yaml file, and it's a total pain in the butt.